# Add corresponding elements in two arrays of different length

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
a = [50, 17, 54, 26]
b = [19, 7, 8, 18, 36, 8, 18, 36, 18, 14]
```

I want to add to the elements of `b` the corresponding elements of `a`. When the elements of `a` runs out, I want to cycle through `a` to supply the elements. The result should be:

```
c = [69, 24, 62, 44, 86, 25, 72, 62, 68, 31]
```

How could I go about this?

Comment: You mean "add elements from one array to **[elements in]** another array," not "add elements from one array to another array". What you wrote sounds like you wanted to concatenate the arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b.zip(a * (b.size / a.size + 1)).map { |o| o.reduce(:+) }
#⇒ [69, 24, 62, 44, 86, 25, 72, 62, 68, 31]
```

Or, much better and more concise from @SimpleLime:

```
b.zip(a.cycle).map(&:sum)
```

Comment: Was just writing something very close: `b.zip(a.cycle).map(&:sum)`

Comment: @SimpleLime yes, yours is way cleaner, I have updated an answer. I always forget about these modern helpers like `#cycle` and `#sum` :)

Comment: Now I even understand the question. Nice solution with cycle.

Comment: @SimpleLime I don't think anyone would have raised any eyebrows had you posted that answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [50, 17, 54, 26]
b = [19, 7, 8, 18, 36, 8, 18, 36, 18, 14]

enum = a.cycle
b.map { |e| e + enum.next }
#=> [69, 24, 62, 44, 86, 25, 72, 62, 68, 31]
```

Comment: Like. Or, without the local variable: `b.each_with_object(a.cycle).map { |e, enum| enum.next + e }`.

Answer (score 0):

Another one, using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map), [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and modulo:

```
b.map.with_index { |e, i| e + a[i % a.size] }
#=> [69, 24, 62, 44, 86, 25, 72, 62, 68, 31]
```

Comment: Apparently, this one was [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323929/add-corresponding-elements-in-two-arrays-of-different-length#comment85650479_49324040) in the comments (hidden below the fold). Credits go to mudasobwa.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Only works in rails

```
def add_arrays(array_a, array_b)
  results = []
  array_b.in_groups_of(4).each do |group|
    group.each_with_index do |record, j|
      results << (record + array_a[j])
    end
  end
  results
end
```

Not tested it but that should do the trick

Comment: `in_groups_of`?!

Comment: In ruby? I doubt.

Comment: @mudasobwa it is a `rails` method (your favorite I know) although it does not belong here since there is no rails tag. It is similar to `each_slice` (actually uses it) but allows you to specify a filler for the slices that are not of the correct size eg. `[1,2,3].in_groups_of(2).to_a #=> [[1,2],[3,nil]]`

Comment: @engineersmnky lol; as nearly everything in Rails it is meaningless; `each_slice` returns an enumerator, and you are not expected to call `to_a` on it, you expect to chain it, where you’ll get your `nil` back: `[1,2,3].each_slice(2).each { |v1, v2| puts [v1, v2].inspect }` :)

Comment: Also slicing here is redundant, use modulo division of the index instead: `b.each.with_index.map { |e, i| e + a[i % a.size] }`.

Comment: @mudasobwa but would you expect me to use parrallel assigment for `each_slice(12)`? chances are that would contain an inner loop of the 12 elements (especially in rails where `in_groups_of` may be used for ui elements and I expect to have 12 on each line (or whatever) even if they are empty.) Side note I have never actually used this method but I do know of its existence because whether or not one thinks rails is a ruby abomination (Frankenstein's Monster if will)  it helps pay my bills :)

Comment: @engineersmnky mine also, tbh :)

Comment: Just a slight nit-pick on the comments: the `each` in `b.each.with_index.map` isn't needed: `b.map.with_index` does the same thing